# Get error [object Text]. It should be an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Trying to get the text from the div with xPath. Finds information in the browser good, but when i try to run with an idea than i get error:"is: [object Text]. It should be an element."

```
       List<WebElement> priceGameWebElement =  webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'search_price')]" +
            "/text()[normalize-space()][1]"));
```

What do I need to do to make everything work?

Comment: Well, you cast your result as `WebElement`, but the last part of your XPath expression selects a `text()` node (and not an `element()` node) with `....../text()[normalize-space()][1]`.

Comment: and what should I do in such a situation? I am only recently studying xPath.I definitely need to get the text that there is div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "interrupt" your query before the `/text()...` part like this:

```
List<WebElement> priceGameWebElement =  webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'search_price')]"));
```

Then you should get a `List<WebElement>` which contains the elements with the `text()` nodes for further distinction. They could probably be queried with the `.getText()` function.

Comment: For example List<WebElement> priceGameWebElement =  webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'search_price')]"));
But where i must use getText ?When I try to call it from the  priceGameWebElement it's not there

Comment: You  have to iterate over the `List<..>`(the `priceGameWebElement`) and then call `.getText()` on each of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you cannot exclude `text()` from XPath and you need just extract the text of the element, then there is a workaround: use method `document.evaluate()` from JavaScript.

Code example:

```
    String textObjectXpath = "\"//*[local-name() = 'text'][@x='8']/text()\"";
    String script = "var element = document.evaluate("
            + textObjectXpath
            + ", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;"
            + "if (element) {return element.nodeValue;}";
    String extractedText = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
```

The if statement `"if (element) {return element.nodeValue;}"` could be omitted if you don't care about the scenario when the element will be without text. In a such case, you may want to replace the line with `"return element.nodeValue;"`